# Unable to assign column names R

Tags: r

Data:

```
CODE                        MTH MAKE                   FAMILY                   VARIANT                        
1                    22  26 29  33                     56                       81                             
-------------------- --- -- --- ---------------------- ------------------------ ------------------------------ 
AUDA6-AL4930J7R2009C        Mar AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO                
AUDA6-AL4930J7R2010A        Jan AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO                
AUDA6-AL4930J7R2011A        Jan AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO                
AUDA6-AL4F30GPJ2007E        May AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO                
AUDA6-AL4F30GPJ2008A        Jan AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO                
AUDA6-AL4F30GPJ2009A        Jan AUDI                   A6                       ALLROAD QUATTRO
```

Could someone please provide some guidance as I am new to programming.
I am trying to read the following file using `read.fwf()` as per the code below. The first row should be headers but because of the fixed width, I am unable to do that.

```
test <- read.fwf(file.choose(),
                 widths = c(21,4,3,4,23,25,31), fill = T)
```

I then take the first row and save it as "headings" as per the code below:

```
headings <- test[1,]
```

I then try to assign the headings as the colnames as per

```
colnames(test) <- headings
```

whilst the code doesn't throw an error, I dont get the desired result i.e the `colnames` are still showing as numbers rather than the names. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip first 3 lines and set colnames manually, like this:

```
test <- read.fwf(file = file.choose(), widths = c(21,4,3,4,23,25,31), strip.white=T, skip=3)
colnames(test) <- c('CODE',' ',' ','MTH','MAKE','FAMILY','VARIANT')
```

Comment: Error in read.table(file = FILE, header = header, sep = sep, row.names = row.names,  : 
  more columns than column names